# UIActivityIndicatorView not disappearing when back page in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

My activity indicator seems not disappear after I go back page. For the first time, it's disappear. Then I go to second view controller then go back to the first view controller. The activity indicator supposedly not to showing up since all UIViews already appeared.

My code

```
var activityView : UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, 50, 50)) as UIActivityIndicatorView

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
Alamofire.request(.POST , "192.168.0.1/test", parameters: [])
            .responseJSON { response in
                if response.result.isSuccess {
                    var jsonObj = JSON(response.result.value!)
                    print(jsonObj)
                    self.activityView.stopAnimating()
                }
        }
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        activityView.center = self.view.center
        activityView.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityView.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
        view.addSubview(activityView)
        activityView.startAnimating()
    }
```

Comment: is those code from the same viewController? viewDidLoad is executed when the VC is being loaded, and viewDidAppear is executed when the VC is finished its loading process and ready to be presented. Since you wrote code to startAnimating at viewDidAppear, it will start animating when when it is appear. Hence why your activity indicator still there.

Answer (score 1):

You are showing your activityIndicator in `viewDidAppear`. That is why it appears when you go back from second to first. Also have a look at [view life cycle](http://roadfiresoftware.com/2015/01/ios-essentials-the-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle/). `viewDidLoad` is only called once whenever view controller is initialized, but `viewDidAppear` will be called when ever the view controller is presented. (either back navigation or presented again)

So its better to add views in `viewDidLoad` and activity indicator should always be associated with its network call. Before starting the call show the activity indicator and hide or remove once its done.

Also, you have missed `super` calls. Be sure to always call super methods when overriding.

Ex:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addActivityIndicator()
    fetchRemoteData()
}

func addActivityIndicator() {
    activityView.center = self.view.center
    activityView.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityView.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
    view.addSubview(activityView)
}

func fetchRemoteData() {
    activityView.startAnimating()
    Alamofire.request(.POST , "192.168.0.1/test", parameters: [])
        .responseJSON { response in
            if response.result.isSuccess {
                var jsonObj = JSON(response.result.value!)
                print(jsonObj)
                self.activityView.stopAnimating()
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin Whats not showing ? Activity Indicator ?

Answer (score 0):

U want to hide and show your activity indicator when you want. And also make sure to set as bringSubviewToFront